ArcGIS Pro SDK 2.9 MapView object has no AddOverlay method
I have an ArcGIS Pro 2.9 Addin where I would like to put overlay graphic on the active mapview, according to ArcGIS Pro SDK documentation, there is AddOverlay method on the MapView object as below:
public static IDisposable AddOverlay( 
   MapView mapView,
   Geometry geometry,
   CIMSymbolReference symbol,
   double referenceScale,
   double showThrough
)

as in:
mapView.AddOverlay(point,
        SymbolFactory.Instance.ConstructPointSymbol(
                ColorFactory.Instance.RedRGB, 30.0, SimpleMarkerStyle.Star).MakeSymbolReference());
  });

But, in the development environment, I cannot find any such 'AddOverlay' method on my MapView object when examining via the . operator, (I can only see 'AddOverlayControl' method), could anyone help where can I access this method?

AddOverlay is an extension method on the static class MappingExtensions.
You would have to add a reference to the ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions DLL and use the method like so:
using ArcGIS.Desktop.Mapping;
...

var mapView = MapView.Active;
MappingExtensions.AddOverlay(mapView, additionalParameters);

The DLL can be found in the ArcGIS Pro installation directory under /bin/Extensions/DesktopExtensions/ArcGIS.Desktop.Extensions.dll
